# Populate DataTables Ajax Json object from PHP using multi tables

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

In my project I'm using DataTables to display my data, which is retrieved from an PHP `echo json_encode`. The PHP page is a script that returns JSON:

```
  {
    "sig1_re": [
      {
        "Ticket_RT": 716771,
        "Cable_de_renvoi": 45,
        "Longueur_de_ligne_(Selt)": 50,
        "Res_LigneCoupee": "short",
        "Ticket_fils": 152321,
        "Numero_ND": "",
        "Gamot_DateFermeture": "",
        "Difference_de_date": "",
        "Supprimer": "<a class='delete'><button>Delete</button></a>"
      },
      {
        "Ticket_RT": 716760,
        "Cable_de_renvoi": 45,
        "Longueur_de_ligne_(Selt)": 67,
        "Res_LigneCoupee": "open",
        "Ticket_fils": "",
        "Numero_ND": "",
        "Gamot_DateFermeture": "",
        "Difference_de_date": "",
        "Supprimer": "<a class='delete'><button>Delete</button></a>"
      }
    ],
    "bad_nd": [
      {
        "Ticket_RT": 716620,
        "Numero_ND": 236598741,
        "Supprimer": "<a class='delete'><button>Delete</button></a>"
      },
      {
        "Ticket_RT": 716577,
        "Numero_ND": 565231583,
        "Supprimer": "<a class='delete'><button>Delete</button></a>"
      }
    ]
  }
```

In my first attempt I had one JS file for each table in my HTLM and that works great, but I repeat the same code a lot and call the JSON echo each time, so I decided to regroup all my code in one JS file.

I managed to export almost all the tables options but I'm having trouble defining some variables; one is `hideFromExport`: I need to only copy the values from the first columns when I click on "COPY" button. The second problem is with `oTable` which I use to delete the row. I would like to set these two variables to be compatible with all my tables. (in my below example I use only two tables but in the actual project I have more).

Live Example: http://live.datatables.net/peceqofo/1/edit

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />            
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 90%;">
      <div class="panel panel-danger" style="margin: 5px;">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
              <b>My Test</b>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="tableA" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Ticket_RT</th>
                          <th>Cable_de_renvoi</th>
                          <th>Longueur_de_ligne_</th>
                          <th>Res_LigneCoupee</th>   
                          <th>Ticket_fils RT</th>
                          <th>Gamot_DateFermeture</th>
                          <th>Numero_ND</th>
                          <th>Gamot_DateFermeture</th>    
                          <th>Supprimer</th>    
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
              </table>    
              <br />
              <table id="tableB" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Ticket_RT</th>
                          <th>Numero_ND</th>
                          <th>Supprimer</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
              </table>    
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/dataRender/ellipsis.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready( function () {

      var jsonData = {};
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUHEbjuIoi?indent=2",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              jsonData = data;
            }
          });

      console.log(jsonData);

      var hideFromExport = [1, 2, 3]; /*<--- How i can custom this for each table individually ?? */

      var options = {
        responsive: true,
        bAutoWidth: true,
        dom: '<"top"lf>Bt<"bottom"pi><"clear">',
        scrollY: 400,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        jQueryUI: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        sScrollX: "70%",
        sScrollXInner: "100%",
        bScrollCollapse: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        searching: false,
        iDisplayLength: 25,
        buttons: [{ /*<--- How i can custom this for each table individually ?? */
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: function(idx, data, node) {
                    var isVisible = table.column(idx).visible();
                    var isNotForExport = $.inArray(idx, hideFromExport) !== -1;
                    return isVisible && !isNotForExport ? true : false;
                  }
                }
              },
              'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        language: {
            url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/French.json",
            buttons: {
                copy: 'Copier Tickets',
                copyTitle: 'Ajouté au presse-papiers',
                copyKeys: 'Appuyez sur <i>ctrl</i> ou <i>\u2318</i> + <i>C</i> pour copier les données du tableau à votre presse-papiers. <br><br>Pour annuler, cliquez sur ce message ou appuyez sur Echap.',
                copySuccess: {
                    _: 'Copiés %d rangs',
                    1: 'Copié 1 rang'
                }
            }
        }
      };    

      function initialize(jsonData) {
           /* --- TableA INIT --- */
           options.aaData  = jsonData.sig1_re;
           options.aoColumns = [
                { "mData": "Ticket_RT" },
                { "mData": "Cable_de_renvoi" },
                { "mData": "Longueur_de_ligne_(Selt)" },
                { "mData": "Res_LigneCoupee" },
                { "mData": "Ticket_fils" },
                { "mData": "Gamot_DateFermeture" },
                { "mData": "Numero_ND" },
                { "mData": "Gamot_DateFermeture" },
                { "mData": "Supprimer" }
           ];
           options.aoColumnDefs = [
                { "title": "Titre 1", "targets": 0 },
                { "title": "Titre 2", "targets": 1 },
                { "title": "Titre 3", "targets": 2 },
                { "title": "Titre 4", "targets": 3 },
                { "title": "Titre 5", "targets": 4 },
                { "title": "Titre 6", "targets": 5 },
                { "title": "Titre 7", "targets": 6 },
                { "title": "Titre 8", "targets": 7 },
                { "title": "Titre 9", "targets": 8 }

                /*{ "targets": 1, "render": $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis(5) }*/
           ];


          $("#tableA").dataTable(options);


          /* --- TableB INIT --- */          
          options.aaData = jsonData.bad_nd;
          options.aoColumns = [
                { "mData": "Ticket_RT" },
                { "mData": "Numero_ND" },
                { "mData": "Supprimer" }
          ];
          options.aoColumnDefs = [
               { "title": "Titre 01", "targets": 0 },
               { "title": "Titre 02", "targets": 1 },
               { "title": "Titre 03", "targets": 2 },

               { "targets": 1, "render": $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis(5) }
          ];


          $("#tableB").dataTable(options);
      }

      initialize(jsonData);

      var oTable = $('#tableA').DataTable(); /*<--- How i can custom this for each table individually ?? */
          $('#tableA').on('click', 'a.delete', function (e) {
              oTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
      });

      // Permet de réduire les commentaires et ajouter tooltip
      $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis = function ( cutoff, wordbreak, escapeHtml ) {
          var esc = function ( t ) {
              return t
                  .replace( /&/g, '&amp;' )
                  .replace( /</g, '&lt;' )
                  .replace( />/g, '&gt;' )
                  .replace( /"/g, '&quot;' );
          };

          return function ( d, type, row ) {
              // Order, search and type get the original data
              if ( type !== 'display' ) {
                  return d;
              }

              if ( typeof d !== 'number' && typeof d !== 'string' ) {
                  return d;
              }

              d = d.toString(); // cast numbers

              if ( d.length < cutoff ) {
                  return d;
              }

              var shortened = d.substr(0, cutoff-1);

              // Find the last white space character in the string
              if ( wordbreak ) {
                  shortened = shortened.replace(/\s([^\s]*)$/, '');
              }

              // Protect against uncontrolled HTML input
              if ( escapeHtml ) {
                  shortened = esc( shortened );
              }

              return '<span class="ellipsis" title="'+esc(d)+'">'+shortened+'&#8230;</span>';
          };
      };

    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution :**

Well after a lot of research i found an solution for the commun button options, now that works good ! Then I have added a button that will delete your selected row(s).

I hope this code will help more guys in the same situation like me !

Enjoy :)

Code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
      <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bfm.css">

      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container" style="width: 90%;">
        <div class="panel panel-danger" style="margin: 5px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h2 class="panel-title">
                <b>My Test</b>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tableA" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>

                <br />

                <table id="tableB" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>    
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/dataRender/ellipsis.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      $(document).ready( function () {

        var jsonData = {}; // get the json object array from php
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTKebXDGdK?indent=2",
              async: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                jsonData = data;
              }
            });

        console.log(jsonData);

        var buttonCommon = { // set default export column 0 (first column)
                exportOptions: {
                    columns:[0]
                }
            };

        var options = { // set options for tables
              responsive: true,
              bAutoWidth: true,
              dom: '<"top"lf>Bt<"bottom"pi><"clear">',
              scrollY: 400,
              scrollCollapse: true,
              jQueryUI: true,
              bProcessing: true,
              sScrollX: "70%",
              sScrollXInner: "100%",
              bScrollCollapse: true,
              bDestroy: true,
              searching: false,
              iDisplayLength: 25,
              buttons: [
                  $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    header: false,
                    extend: 'copyHtml5'
                  }),
                  'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5',
                  {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) { // function to delete selected rows on click button
                        dt.data().rows('.selected').remove().draw( false );
                    }
                  }
              ],
              language: {
                  url: "json/French.json",
                  buttons: {
                      copy: 'Copy',
                      copyTitle: 'Ajouté au presse-papiers',
                      copyKeys: 'Appuyez sur <i>ctrl</i> ou <i>\u2318</i> + <i>C</i> pour copier les données du tableau à votre presse-papiers. <br><br>Pour annuler, cliquez sur ce message ou appuyez sur Echap.',
                      copySuccess: {
                          _: 'Copiés %d rangs',
                          1: 'Copié 1 rang'
                      }
                  }
              }
            };    

        function initialize(jsonData) {
             /* --- TableA INIT --- */
             options.aaData  = jsonData.sig1_re;
             options.aoColumns = [
                  { "mData": "Ticket_RT" },
                  { "mData": "Cable_de_renvoi" },
                  { "mData": "Longueur_de_ligne_(Selt)" },
                  { "mData": "Res_LigneCoupee" },
                  { "mData": "Ticket_fils" },
                  { "mData": "Gamot_DateFermeture" },
                  { "mData": "Numero_ND" },
                  { "mData": "Difference_de_date" }
             ];
             options.aoColumnDefs = [
                  { "title": "Titre 1", "targets": 0 },
                  { "title": "Titre 2", "targets": 1 },
                  { "title": "Titre 3", "targets": 2 },
                  { "title": "Titre 4", "targets": 3 },
                  { "title": "Titre 5", "targets": 4 },
                  { "title": "Titre 6", "targets": 5 },
                  { "title": "Titre 7", "targets": 6 },
                  { "title": "Titre 8", "targets": 7 }

                  /*{ "targets": 1, "render": $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis(5) }*/
             ];


            $("#tableA").dataTable(options);

            /* --- TableB INIT --- */          
            options.aaData = jsonData.bad_nd;
            options.aoColumns = [
                  { "mData": "Ticket_RT" },
                  { "mData": "Numero_ND" }
            ];
            options.aoColumnDefs = [
                 { "title": "Titre 01", "targets": 0 },
                 { "title": "Titre 02", "targets": 1 },

                 { "targets": 1, "render": $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis(5) } // call function to render + tooltip
            ];


            $("#tableB").dataTable(options);
        }

        initialize(jsonData);

        $('#tableA tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () { // set multi select rows
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        $('#tableB tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () { // set multi select rows
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        // Function to delimit render + tootil
        $.fn.DataTable.render.ellipsis = function ( cutoff, wordbreak, escapeHtml ) {
            var esc = function ( t ) {
                return t
                    .replace( /&/g, '&amp;' )
                    .replace( /</g, '&lt;' )
                    .replace( />/g, '&gt;' )
                    .replace( /"/g, '&quot;' );
            };

            return function ( d, type, row ) {
                // Order, search and type get the original data
                if ( type !== 'display' ) {
                    return d;
                }

                if ( typeof d !== 'number' && typeof d !== 'string' ) {
                    return d;
                }

                d = d.toString(); // cast numbers

                if ( d.length < cutoff ) {
                    return d;
                }

                var shortened = d.substr(0, cutoff-1);

                // Find the last white space character in the string
                if ( wordbreak ) {
                    shortened = shortened.replace(/\s([^\s]*)$/, '');
                }

                // Protect against uncontrolled HTML input
                if ( escapeHtml ) {
                    shortened = esc( shortened );
                }

                return '<span class="ellipsis" title="'+esc(d)+'">'+shortened+'&#8230;</span>';
            };
        };

      });

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: "I would like to set these two variables to be compatible with all my tables" - can you elaborate/clarify what you want? This doesn't really make sense as written. `hideFromExport` is just an array; it should already be *compatible* with all tables, and oTable is the object that refers to one of the table's API instance. You'll need to have a separate object if you want to refer to a separate table's API instance.

Comment: Why on earth was this question downvoted ...?

Comment: For tables I use common options but I want separate options to manage specific tables. Like settings the `hideFromExport`, example for first table only third column and for the second table only the second. Then I add a delete button for each row but I don't know how to manage it to do the job. If it's not enough clear tell me it. And I don't know why this question was downvoted...Thanks for the help.

Comment: So then don't use common options(?). Make new options for new tables? Is there a particular reason you can't just do that?

Comment: The problem is that I already initialize options for tables so I can't callback it again ti add more options. Perhaps I doing it badly. Make the test and give me a feedback please.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you have more than one options object, one for each table, with separate initialization. When you create `var options` that isn't barring you from creating another object (the name doesn't matter) and passing that to the next table.

Comment: Your suggestion is not bad but I don't want to repeat code again, if you read my first post I already do that in my actual project and that works great. My goal is to merge all in one file and with smart code ;-)

Comment: You could modify the options object between table initializations. E.g. `options.buttons = /*new buttons array*/` between the first table and second table initializations. I *believe* that once the datatable is initialized, the object used for the options can be changed/deleted without affecting the table.

Comment: @Chris H. : i already tried this method too but the console return this error `ReferenceError: table is not defined` because initially this options is called like that :
`var table = $('#tableA').DataTable( { 
/* list of options */
});`

Comment: Live example : http://jsbin.com/xoqadozesa/edit?js,output

Comment: Finally i found the solution by myself, by the way thanks to every one :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the tables separate with attributes. And if you would like to add extra columns and buttons in data tables. You can achieve that using following approach.

1. Add an extra column for **action**.
2. On **fnRowCallback** method add specific class to the action column.

**Example of click on action:**

```
jQuery('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.action', function () {

     //call custom method to format the data inside td.action column.
     data = {
              'id': $(this).attr('cour_id')
            };

     tr.after(format(data)).show();
});
```

It will create action button for each row with specific row ids and attributes and won't conflict with each other.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Sorry but i don't really understand your approach (my english is not very good). Could you give me an example from my last code, please ?